# R - Type Casting With Map()

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I would like to create a new column that extracts the hour from a timestamp as a numeric data type. If I had one data frame or tibble, I would do it as follows:

`calories_hourly$activity_hour_num <- calories_hourly$activity_hour %>% mdy_hms() %>% format(format = ('%H')) %>% as.numeric()`

However, I have one list of 18 tibbles called "fitbit_data" where I would like to perform the operation above for tibbles 6-16. The type casting is calculated from the second column in all of my tibbles. I have an example of the beginning of a failed attempt below:

`fitbit_data[6:16] <- fitbit_data[6:16] %>% mutate(activity_hour_num=map(.x=fitbit_data[6:16], .f=~mdy(.x[2])))`

Can you please help me code a tidy solution for this R task?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` as -

```
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

k <- 6:16

fitbit_data[k] <- map(fitbit_data[k], ~{.x[[2]] <- lubridate::mdy(.x[[2]]);.x})
```

Based on the first attempt you can do -

```
fitbit_data[k] <- map(fitbit_data[k], ~.x %>% 
                        mutate(activity_hour = mdy_hms(activity_hour) %>% 
                                               format('%H') %>% as.numeric()))
```

Comment: Thank you! It gave me exactly what I needed. Would you be so kind as to explain the reason for `~.x %>%` inside the map() function? I thought `fitbit_data[k]` served as the ".x"?

Comment: `mutate` needs a dataframe as input, `fitbit_data[k]` is a list of dataframes. Using `map` we apply the function to each dataframe individually.